# NPM won't install serialport on raspberry pi 1b

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I ran npm install serialport but I get a python error

```
alfred@alfred:~/AccentaG4/src/mpu/server $ python --version
Python 3.9.2

> @serialport/bindings@9.2.8 install /home/alfred/AccentaG4/src/mpu/server/node_modules/@serialport/bindings
> prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=11.15.0 runtime=node arch=arm libc= platform=linux)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:299:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:614:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 6.1.21+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/bin/node" "/usr/local/node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/alfred/AccentaG4/src/mpu/server/node_modules/@serialport/bindings
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN ws@8.13.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@8.13.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@>=5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @serialport/bindings@9.2.8 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@9.2.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Heres the full log

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1awB3tnTxyS4MEFdzmloECIoeFzl9fGo2UjV6OjwOVnE/edit?usp=sharing

I am wondering do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` without brackets is not allowed in python `3`.

```py
print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

↑ is a python `2` syntax, for python 3 it should looks like ↓

```py
print("%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3])
```

Your `node` and `node-gyp` versions are outdated. Newer versions of `node-gyp` [support](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1687#issuecomment-541471076) python `3`

If it not possible to update `node` libraries in your environment you have to [downgrade default python](https://raspberrytips.com/change-default-python-version/) version to `2`